# how to get array value in another page

Tags: php

page1.php

```
$destinationCity = $_POST['destination'];
$sr = new searchArray();
$final = $sr->searcharray($destinationCity);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
echo $final->vc[0];
echo "</pre>";
```

Page2.php

```
class searchArray {

public function searcharray($arr) {
   $rst = array();
   $length = strlen($arr);
    if ($length == 2){
        $sql = "select code from ukhotels where postcode LIKE '$arr%'";
        $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
        while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)){
        $co = $rs['code'];
        $vc = &$rst['vc'];
        $vi = &$rst['vi'];

        $vc[] = substr($co, 0, 2);
        $vi[] = substr($co, 3, strlen($co));

    }

    }
```

In page1 i am calling the function with one argument. In the page2 i am keeping the results in an associate array.

When I am printing the array from page1 its showing me output as

```
Array
(
[vc] => Array
    (
        [0] => CB
        [1] => RD
        [2] => RT
        [3] => YX
    )

[vi] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01461 
        [1] => 95101 
        [2] => 30818 
        [3] => 77126 
    )

)
```

i wanted to use the array in page1 like this

```
for($i=0, $j=1;$i<=20;$i++)
{
$params["VendorLocation"]["VendorCode"] = "{$final->vc[$i]}";
$params["VendorLocation"]["VendorLocationID"] = "{$final->vi[$i]}";
$params["VendorLocation"]["Key"] = "{$j}";
$j++;
}
```

but it is throwing me an error saying " Notice: Trying to get property of non-object "

Can any one please help me how to solve this issues.

Regards
Hailey

Comment: 5 second look here and tl;dr, but one problem might be because $i iterates to 20 and you havent got 20 items probably. Try setting $i to the length of vc. Also vc and vi are array properties not object properties, try accessing like `$final['vc']`. This can be clearly seen in the print out.

Comment: on which line it is showing this `" Notice: Trying to get property of non-object "`??

Comment: The line where you get that error is missing. Also you have not shared which part of the error message you wonder about. Which one is not clear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$final is an array, access the value like this :

```
for($i=0, $j=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
    $params["VendorLocation"]["VendorCode"] = '{' . $final['vc'][$i] . '}';
    $params["VendorLocation"]["VendorLocationID"] = '{' . $final['vi'][$i] . '}';
    $params["VendorLocation"]["Key"] = "{$j}";
    $j++;
}
```